# How to deal with NPOT texture mipmap generation in OpenGL, keeping scanline alignment in mind?

Tags: opengl

I have the following situation:

- A non-power-of-two (NPOT) texture, in RGB format.
- I add some padding at the right side of my texture to [make sure the texture scanlines are a multiple of 4 bytes](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Texture_upload_and_pixel_reads).
- I need mipmap generation.
- `glGenerateMipmaps()` is unreliable (I believe it is actually broken on the Intel HD Graphics 3000 driver from Apple, as it gives wrong results, but correct results on Linux, same device) and slow (again on the Apple driver for my chip, fast on Linux).

To address the last problem, I decided I want to do mipmap generation "manually" using framebuffers with a render to texture approach.

However, I'm stuck at how I should deal with the padding to make the scanlines multiples of four bytes, while having consitent mipmap sampling in the shader. Without mipmaps, I'm using a `uniform vec2` that I use to multiply the `uv` with in order to compensate for the few columns of padding at the right side of the texture. Now, the problem is that at every level of mipmap, I have to do the padding to make the scanlines 4-bytes-aligned; but this padding can be different at every level, which would require me to use a different `uv`-multiplier for every level, which is something I can't do in a shader, because I want to use automatic LOD (level of detail) selection when sampling.

I guess that this question is equivalent to: "What does a succesfull `glGenerateMipmaps` algorithm do in my scenario?" The documenation on this function is very short. Actually I'm surprised the Linux driver does the job right, in my complex scenario.

Easy solutions that are not acceptable in my scenario (because of the increase in memory usage):

- Use RGBA format such that the scanlines are always 4-bytes-aligned.
- Use POT textures such that the scanlines are always 4-bytes-aligned.

Comment: Afaik, 4 byte alignment is only required in case of GPU->CPU transfers (and the other way round), but never influence the textures in a shader. Unless you increase the size parameter of `glTexImage2D` by the padding, I don't see why the padding would influence mipmap generation or automatic mipmap lookups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I add some padding at the right side of my texture to make sure the texture scanlines are a multiple of 4 bytes.

Well, stop doing that. The article you link to doesn't say "always make your textures aligned to 4 bytes". It says to make sure that your byte alignment in your uploaded texture data matches the pixel pack byte alignment you give to OpenGL.

Just make your texture sizes what you need them to be, then upload the data with the proper alignment. Texture widths do not need to be multiples of 4.

Comment: Ah, nice! Thank you so much for clearing that out. (I was hoping you would answer this :P )